# Convert flow + suspending update function to a valid compose MutableState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to provide a `MutableState` for custom implementations for a library. The demands are like following:

- I have a suspending update function
- I have flow for getting the current data

In my case have this flow and that function for my app settings and now I want to convert that setting into a `MutableState`. My first idea is following:

```kotlin
// StorageSetting... an interface that allows to read/update/observe some data:
// reading via a flow and a suspending read function
// updating via a suspending write function
// => in the background this setting may be backed up by a room database, a preference file, whatever...
@Composable
fun <T> StorageSetting<T>.asMutableState(): MutableState<T> {
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    // StorageSetting has a flow field returning a kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
    val flowState = flow.collectAsState()
    // delegate changes from the flow to the state
    LaunchedEffect(flowState.value) {
        state.value = internalState.value
    }
    // delegate changes from the state to the suspend update function
    LaunchedEffect(state.value) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // StorageSetting has a suspending update function
            update(state.value)
        }
    }
    return state
}
```

Now I wonder if there is a better way to use a `Flow` and a suspending update function and wrap that somehow in a `MutableState`.

Any ideas or feedback?

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend using `DisposableEffect`.

```
val state = remember { mutableStateOf(yourGenericType) }

DisposableEffect(yourFlow) {
        val collector = yourFlow.onEach { state.value = it }.launchIn(CompositionLocalProvided(Dispatchers.Main))

        onDispose {
            collector.cancel()
        }
    }
```

You can shape the `Dispatcher` according to your needs.